# Error XAGJS7009: System.InvalidOperationException: There can be only one type with an [Application] attribute android Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

After implementing Huawei push service in my android project, I was getting crash on the occurrence of Push Notification, and error was looged

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void crc6415d7e49b4cd3bc6f.MyApplication.n_onCreate()**

To resolve this error, I crated MyApplication to extend the Application.

```
[Application]
    public class MyApplication : Application
    {
        public MyApplication(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
        {

        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
        }
    }
```

then I am getting

**Error XAGJS7009: System.InvalidOperationException: There can be only one type with an [Application] attribute; found:**,

*Note*

1. I have tried adding these lines as well

```
    #if DEBUG
    [Application(Debuggable=true)]
    #else
    [Application(Debuggable=false)]
    #endif
```

but still getting the same issue

2. Already tried Clean and Rebuild solution

Comment: Try to not call `base.OnCreate` in `OnCreate`.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yeah, I tried by not calling base.OnCreate, but still getting the same error.

Comment: It looks like a Huawei push service issue and wait for next version to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete **Application file** first. Open **The Library** project then find **XPush-5.0.2.300** -> **HmsPush** -> **Application file** then delete it.

Then add below code line to your Application's **OnCreate()** method if you want to use feature which is relevant to it.

```
RegisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyLifecycleHandler());
```

In addition this problem will be fixed in the [next version](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/version-change-history-0000001050136488).

Comment: I have done it, but now again I am getting `"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void crc6415d7e49b4cd3bc6f.MyApplication.n_onCreate()"` on occurance of push notification

Comment: @PrashantGautam Please try to clean and delete **obj and bin folder** of main project before Build, and see if it works.